# Ball Shaper for Batter

Tags: equipment

Does anyone know of any ball shaper for Falafel Batter?
I was looking for a shaper, that could i could load with some falafel batter and directly load it into the fryer in a shape of a ball.
-AFM

Comment: Would this work? http://www.amazon.com/OXO-Grips-Small-Cookie-Scoop/dp/B0000CCY1E/ref=sr_1_1?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1381612728&sr=1-1&keywords=cookie+scooper I have all of the sizes, I can vouch for the product.

Answer (score 3):

Most restaurants that I have seen that make falafel use a little plunger thing like this:
 [image]
You load the cavity with the falafel mix, then push the plunger and it pushes the ball out.

If you can't find that, I'd think that any appropriately sized portion scoop would do (probably something like a #24).

[image]

Comment: The first one produced Disc/Cyclindrival shaped falafel. Does the second one has a releasing mechanism for releasing the falafel balls?

Comment: I think that's the more traditionally used tool. If you want a ball, you'd be better off with the portion scoop (though it will still have a bit of a flat side, you may have to roll them a bit by hand).

Comment: @jennett and yes, the 2nd has a method for releasing the dough. When you click the trigger on the side of the scoop, it sweeps a wire across the inside surface, pushing the food out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a specialty piece of equipment called a falafel ball scoop or falafel press.

[image]

You have to be quite patient, but [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSMASCvQ3jU) demonstrates the technique:  loading the bell of the press with the batter, then using the thumb trigger to squeeze it out directly into the oil for frying.